# How to get focus of QLineEdit in Qt4.5

Tags: qt

When i click Qlineedit i want the focus and at the same time i want to edit for multiple linedits for using virtual keyboard.

Comment: Please clarify: where do you want the focus - how do you plan to edit several line-edits at the same time? Also the tag isn't related to the question.

Comment: Basically i want to use virtual keyboard. Suppose  say, if 10 QLineEdit is there. I want the focus of which Qlineedit i clicked and at the same time i want to edit with virtual keyboard. Am i clear myself?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass QLineEdit and implement QWidget::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *); and set a global variable to the current linedit and use that from your virtual keyboard.

ex (not real code) :

```
void myLineEdit::focusInEvent ( QFocusEvent * ) {
     myapp->currentLineEdit = this;
 }
 //virtual keyboard 
 if(myapp->currentLineEdit) abuse(myapp->currentLineEdit);
```